# Is there an easy way to list CLI tools installed on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem, storage

So I have various command line tools like node, stats, etc which help me with day to day tasks, however I've noticed they don't show up in storage manager under applications and am unsure if there's a way to list all of those tools and completely remove all the files of the ones I don't use any more. It'll show as extra system memory use. It's not a big deal however I don't want to waste space. Is there a tool to manage all of this?

Answer (score 3):

Basically every directory listed in `PATH` besides the standard ones (`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`) contains user-installed, so running `ls` on these directories gives you the list for them and you can use the usual Unix tools like `du` to calculate sizes.

To make managing user-installed tools easier you can rely on a package manager. [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) is the package manager of choice for many users.

Comment: Don't forget /usr/local/bin.

Answer (score 2):

You should also look at the manual page for [`hier`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man7/hier.7.html), as it provides a historical sketch of the filesystem hierarchy, which you might find informational in reference to your question. You can run `ls` in Terminal on any of directories listed, to get a listing, or look at them through Finder > Go > Go to Folder... and type in the path, e.g.: `/usr/bin`